# Iptables routing port 80 to local lan machine

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have cloud machine with public ip on eth0 and other interface zerotier have local machines with homeassistant https://192.168.0.15:8123. This cloud machine can access https://192.168.0.15:8123 over zerotier. I would like to route incoming traffic eth0 to homeassistant.

incoming public ip -> eth0 -> zerotier interface https://192.168.0.15:8123 i was trying:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1 
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.15:8123 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.15 --dport 8123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

when tcpdump -i eth0 port 8123 i got incoming packets on port 8123 but nothing coming back from homeassistant

i figure it out this is working

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -d 192.168.0.15 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.15:8123
```

Comment: What is the configured default gateway in homeassistant?

Comment: thanks for trying helping me

Comment: You should either answer your own question, or delete it. Don't put the answer in the question itself.